# Getting value from array in a SELECT statement in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have created a table in postgresql with column as jsonb

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table ( data jsonb );
```

And I have inserted the values inside jsonb

```
INSERT INTO my_table ("data") VALUES ('{"id":"100100","my_array":[{"createdTime":1629686783,"updatedTime":1632365183,"status":"Initiated","my_array_id":"12345678"},{"createdTime":1627008383,"updatedTime":1627008383,"status":"Completed","my_array_id":"789010111"}]}');
```

How can I get inserted value using select query in PostgreSQL. I have used the below , but it is returning empty results

```
select *
from my_table 
where (not data->'my_array' ??| array[cast('{"12345678"}' as varchar[])])
```

Kindly help

Comment: Can you clarify your question pls?   Maybe all records from my_table in which my_array is containing value 12345678..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to get all records from 'my_table' where my_array_id is different from a certain value. In this case 12345678.

In any case, you need to use the **jsonb_array_elements** function in order to access the particular item from the array, and after that arrow '->>' in order to access the particular attribute from that item(json).
This is the query for the aforementioned assumption.

```
with temp_CTE as
(
  select  m.*,jsonb_array_elements(m.data->'my_array')->>'my_array_id' as my_array_id   from my_table m
)
select * from   temp_CTE c
where c.my_array_id<>'12345678'
```